# Google Chrome Gamepad JavaScript API with Playstation Buzz Controller

Tags: javascript, api, gamepad, buzz

**Google Chrome GamePad API Bug**

I think there must be somewhere a bug in the **javascript Google Chrome gamepad api**. I am using the USB playstation BUZZ! buzzer (20 buttons) controller.

The first button gp.buttons[0].pressed is always pressed even if it is not really pressed. All other buttons work fine.

```
>> buttons: Array[20] 
>> 0: GamepadButton 
>> pressed: true 
>> value: 1
```

In the gamepad controller overview (windows hardware/devices) the buzz controller works for all 20 buttons fine.

Regards,
                Alex

Comment: It must be a bug in the Google Chrome Browsers Gamepad API. In Firefox the same code works perfect for all 20 Buttons.

Comment: Reported as a bug in Chronium. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393164